# The performance of AceFEM in Intel Processor VS. AMD Processor

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen, system-performance, mkl

I am going to buy a new powerful desktop that I will use to run finite element simulations using AceFEM. I found out that the new AMD Ryzen 9 3950X obtained more points in the CPU Passmark benchmark compared to the Intel processors [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBFgjl.png). I would like to know how well it works with AceFEM that uses linear solvers from the MKL library (both direct Pardiso and iterative CG) and performs well with Intel processors. On the other hand, the AMD processors are not as good as Intel processors in working with MKL library. For instance, it has been observed that in Matlab, which uses MKL library, the new AMD processors were not as good as Intel processors. However, after some tweaking, the performance of AMD processors increased significantly [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8hil.png).

I would like to know if anyone has experience in working with AceFEM with AMD processors? In particular, the new AMD processors, e.g. Ryzen 9 3900, 3900X or 3950X. Can AMD processors compete with Intel processors?

Just in case someone has AMD processors, I would like to do a simple test for which I will provide the related code.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBFgjl.png) https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Ryzen+9+3950X&id=3598

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8hil.png) https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-MKL-with-AMD-Ryzen-and-Threadripper-CPU-s-Effectively-for-Python-Numpy-And-Other-Applications-1637

**Edit**

I have prepared a sample simulation to test the performance of the CPUs. The compression of a hyperelastic material (with Neo-Hookean elastic strain energy) is considered, where the Neumann boundary conditions are prescribed to induce the compression within 10 time-steps. It is important to test the performance with both direct and iterative solvers. The material element (AceGen code) and the simulations (for both direct and iterative solvers) are provided below.

*AceGen code*

```
<< AceGen`;

nNodes = 8;
nhdata = 9;
SMSInitialize["HEISONEO", "Environment" -> "AceFEM"];
SMSTemplate["SMSTopology" -> "H1", "SMSNoNodes" -> nNodes, 
  "SMSDOFGlobal" -> Table[3, nNodes], 
  "SMSNodeID" -> Table["D", nNodes], "SMSSymmetricTangent" -> True, 
  "SMSDefaultIntegrationCode" -> 11, 
  "SMSNoElementData" -> nhdata es$$["id", "NoIntPoints"], 
  "SMSDomainDataNames" -> {"Ee -elastic modulus", 
    "ν -Poisson ratio"}];

SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"];

initialization1[] := (
   Xi ⊢ SMSReal[Table[nd$$[i, "X", j], {i, nNodes}, {j, 3}]];
   ui ⊢ 
    SMSReal[Table[nd$$[i, "at", j], {i, nNodes}, {j, 3}]];
   
   {Ee, ν} ⊢ 
    SMSReal[Table[es$$["Data", i], {i, Length[SMSDomainDataNames]}]];
   );

initialization1[];

SMSDo[Ig, 1, SMSInteger[es$$["id", "NoIntPoints"]]];

initialization2[] := (
   Ξ = {ξ, η, ζ} ⊢ 
     Table[SMSReal[es$$["IntPoints", i, Ig]], {i, 3}];
   Nodeξηζ = {{-1 , -1 , -1} , {1 , -1 , -1} , {1 , 
      1 , -1} , {-1 , 1 , -1} , {-1 , -1 , 1} , {1 , -1 , 1} , {1 , 
      1 , 1} , {-1 , 1 , 1}};
   Ni ⊨ 
    Table[1/8 (1 + ξ Nodeξηζ[[i , 
          1]]) (1 + η Nodeξηζ[[i, 
          2]]) (1 + ζ Nodeξηζ[[i, 3]]) , {i , 
      1 , 8}];
   X ⊨ SMSFreeze[Ni.Xi];
   u ⊨ Ni.ui;
   
   Jg ⊨ SMSD[X, Ξ];
   Jgd ⊨ Det[Jg];
   
   \[DoubleStruckCapitalH] ⊨ 
    SMSD[u, X, "Dependency" -> {Ξ, X, SMSInverse[Jg]}];
   Ii ⊨ IdentityMatrix[3];
   F ⊨ SMSFreeze[Ii + \[DoubleStruckCapitalH]];
   
   SMSFreeze[Fe, F, "Ignore" -> PossibleZeroQ];
   SMSExport[Flatten[Fe], ed$$["Data", (Ig - 1) nhdata + #] &];
   Ce ⊨ Transpose[Fe].Fe;
   be ⊨ Fe.Transpose[Fe];
   Je ⊨ SMSSqrt[Det[be]];
   
   {μ, κ} ⊨ SMSHookeToBulk[Ee, ν];
   W ⊨ κ/2 (1/2 (Je^2 - 1) - Log[Je]) + μ/
      2 (Tr[Je^(-2/3) be] - 3);
   
   wgp ⊨ SMSReal[es$$["IntPoints", 4, Ig]];
   );

initialization2[];

pe = Flatten[ui];

SMSDo[
  Rg ⊨ Jgd wgp (SMSD[W, pe, i]);
  SMSExport[SMSResidualSign Rg, p$$[i], "AddIn" -> True];
  SMSDo[
   Kg ⊨ SMSD[Rg, pe, j];
   SMSExport[Kg, s$$[i, j], "AddIn" -> True];
   , {j, SMSNoDOFGlobal}];
  , {i, SMSNoDOFGlobal}];
SMSEndDo[];

SMSStandardModule["Postprocessing"];

initialization1[];
SMSNPostNames = {"DeformedMeshX", "DeformedMeshY", "DeformedMeshZ"};
SMSExport[Table[ui[[i]], {i, 8}], npost$$];

SMSWrite[];

SMTMakeDll[];
```

*Test 1: Direct solver*

```
<< AceFEM`;

width = 200;
depth = 200;
height = 200;
nx = 50;
ny = 50;
nz = 50;

points = {{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, depth, 0}, {0, depth, 
    0}, {0, 0, height}, {width, 0, height}, {width, depth, 
    height}, {0, depth, height}};

SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain[{"A", "HEISONEO", {"Ee *" -> 107.2, "ν *" -> 0.36}}];
SMTAddMesh[Hexahedron[points], "A", "H1", {nx, ny, nz}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, depth, 0}, {0, depth, 
     0}}, "D"], 3 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, depth, 0}, {0, depth, height}, {0, 0, 
     height}}, "D"], 1 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, 0, height}, {0, 0, 
     height}}, "D"], 2 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, height}, {width/2, 0, height}, {width/2, depth/2, 
     height}, {0, depth/2, height}}, "D"], 3 -> -18];
SMTAnalysis["Output" -> "testSolver5Mat2.out"];
SMTSetSolver[5, "MatrixType" -> 2];

velocity = 10;
fd = {{0, 0}};
λf[t_] := velocity t;

SMTNextStep["Δt" -> 4/velocity, 
  "λ[t]" -> λf];

While[
  While[
   step = 
    SMTConvergence[1*10^-12, 
     16, {"Adaptive Time", 8, 4/velocity, 4/velocity, 40/velocity}], 
   SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   Print["Error: Δt < Δtmin"]];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   SMTStatusReport[
     "ΔT<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ΔT\), \(min\
\)]\)"];];
  step[[3]], If[step[[1]], SMTStepBack[];];
  SMTNextStep["Δt" -> step[[2]], 
   "λ[t]" -> λf];
  ];

SMTSimulationReport[]
```

*Test2: Iterative solver*

```
<< AceFEM`;

width = 200;
depth = 200;
height = 200;
nx = 50;
ny = 50;
nz = 50;

points = {{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, depth, 0}, {0, depth, 
    0}, {0, 0, height}, {width, 0, height}, {width, depth, 
    height}, {0, depth, height}};

SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain[{"A", "HEISONEO", {"Ee *" -> 107.2, "ν *" -> 0.36}}];
SMTAddMesh[Hexahedron[points], "A", "H1", {nx, ny, nz}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, depth, 0}, {0, depth, 
     0}}, "D"], 3 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, depth, 0}, {0, depth, height}, {0, 0, 
     height}}, "D"], 1 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, 0, height}, {0, 0, 
     height}}, "D"], 2 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, height}, {width/2, 0, height}, {width/2, depth/2, 
     height}, {0, depth/2, height}}, "D"], 3 -> -18];
SMTAnalysis["Output" -> "testSolver6Mat2.out"];
SMTSetSolver[6, "MatrixType" -> 2, "IterativeSolverType" -> 2, 
  "Preconditioner" -> 3];

velocity = 10;
fd = {{0, 0}};
λf[t_] := velocity t;

SMTNextStep["Δt" -> 4/velocity, 
  "λ[t]" -> λf];

While[
  While[
   step = 
    SMTConvergence[1*10^-12, 
     16, {"Adaptive Time", 8, 4/velocity, 4/velocity, 40/velocity}], 
   SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   Print["Error: Δt < Δtmin"]];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   SMTStatusReport[
     "ΔT<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ΔT\), \(min\
\)]\)"];];
  step[[3]], If[step[[1]], SMTStepBack[];];
  SMTNextStep["Δt" -> step[[2]], 
   "λ[t]" -> λf];
  ];

SMTSimulationReport[]
```

I have performed the simulations with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6950X CPU, Windows 64 bit, AceFEM version 6.823, and the simulation reports for direct and iterative solver are as follows.

[image: direct solver]

[image: iterative solver]

**Update (2/1/2023)**

We recently bought a new desktop equipped with Intel Core i7-13700k CPU. It has 8 performance cores (16 threads) and 8 efficient cores (8 threads). The results of the test are as follows:

*Direct solver:*

[image: direct_new_noraml]

*Direct solver (affinity tweaked): Efficient cores not involved*

[image]

*Iterative solver:*

[image: Iterative_new_normal]

*Iterative solver (affinity tweaked): Efficient cores not involved*

[image]

It shows that when only performance cores are at play, the computational efficiency (mostly of linear solver) exhibits 10%-20% improvement.

Comment: I am running AceGen/AceFEM on AMD Ryzen 3900X processor, but I have zero experience with testing. Nevertheless, if you will provide the test I will gladly run it.

Comment: @marko thanks a lot for your response. Please see the edited post. I have provided the material element (AceGen code) and the simulations (for both direct and iterative solvers) for you. Everything is ready to be evaluated. Please, run both simulations and provide the output files. My simulation reports are presented above (just in case you want to compare your results). It would be informative if you could also provide information regarding the operating system and the AceFEM version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have performed the simulations with an AMD Ryzen 3900X CPU, Windows 64 bit, AceFEM version 7.103.
Maybe someone can provide some comment to the obtained results and how they compare the the results on Intel i7.

Direct solver simulation report:
[image: Direct solver]

Iterative solver simulation report:
[image: Iterative solver]

EDIT:

As per KratosMath request, this is a snapshot of some of my environmental variables
[image: environmental variables]

EDIT 2:

After following the suggestion by Karel Tůma, the direct solver time becomes considerably shorter

New direct solver report:
[image: direct solver 2]

New iterative solver report:
[image: Iterative solver 2]

EDIT 3:

A colleague at work is working on Intel i9 9920X processor, Windows 64 bit, AceFEM version 7.103. I asked him to run the test. Below are his environmental variables and test results, where the absolute time is roughly 30% faster than with my Ryzen.

[image: Environmental var 1]

Direct solver:

[image: Direct solv 1]

Iterative solver

[image: Iterative solv 1]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. It appears that 3900x has a better performance when it comes to the iterative solvers. This can be understood by comparing the total absolute time, which comprises the total assembly time and total solver time. However, regarding the direct solver, Intel has a twice better performance. Is it possible for you to also provide your environment variables?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought there was more to it than just the absolute time. What do you mean by environment variables?

Comment: Well, the absolute time is just an indication of the overall performance. It appears that 3900x gives a better assembly time in both direct and linear solvers. However, in the direct solver case, it has a twice poorer performance in terms of the solver time. 
It is good to check the environment variables of your windows to have a better understanding of the situation. To check the environment variables, right-click on the computer icon from the desktop, choose properties, advanced system settings. Then, in the Advanced tab, choose Environment variables. A snapshot is sufficient.

Comment: The reason why the assembly of the residuum and tangent matrix is much faster with AMD is that for the assembly AceGen generates a C code that is compiled with a compiler that works fine with AMD. The linear solver is using the MKL library which seems to be the bottleneck. @marko, can you please try adding a new environment variable? See picture: https://www.pugetsystems.com/pic_disp.php?id=58487 Then please test the direct solver again, if it is better, also the iterative one. We are interested mainly in the CPU time needed for the linear solver, it was expected that K&R will be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update.

Comment: Is it possible for you to try as suggested by Karel in the other response? It would be nice to see if this workaround would boost the performance or not.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable effort. Your final results lead us to the conclusion that the tweaking indeed helps to accelerate the solver time in AceFEM. However, it should be noted that the effectivity of this workaround is not guaranteed in all possible combinations of AMD processors and MKL libraries.

Comment: @marko can we check the Performance of OpenMPI for ACEFEM?

Comment: @KarelTůma can we check the Performance of OpenMPI for ACEFEM?

Comment: Sure, what do you suggest?

Comment: @KratosMath: As it is written in the reference [2] MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5 is not documented anywhere. Thus, the main danger is that Intel can remove this possibility from the new versions of the library. However, it seems that turning on AVX2 is not enough, becase AMD Ryzen 9 3900X obtained in Passmark almost 1.9 times more points than Intel i7 6950X, but cpu time of the direct solver is just comparable...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM what do you suggest for checking the performance of OpenMPI for AceFEM?

Comment: @KratosMath I have added results also for i9 processor. Ss for any other tests, I am willing to help by running any similar code, but you must provide the test code.

Comment: @KratosMath you may check this: https://www.wolfram.com/gridmathematica/